How to disable the text editing in DropdownMenu<T> class?
Is it possible to disable the DropdownMenu class from free text editing by the user (i.e. the dropdown fields are read-only)

  DropdownMenu(
            width: maxWidth,
            initialSelection: state.current,
            dropdownMenuEntries: options.map(
              (e) {
                return DropdownMenuEntry(
          
                  value: e,
                  label: e.name ?? "",
                  labelWidget: SizedBox(
                    width: size.width,
                    child: Text(
                      e.name ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                );

